# How to create android swipe-sensitive area pulls a layout up into the visible area

Tags: android, kotlin, swipe

The biggest problem is that I can't formulate my question, so I couldn't even search for the solution. I don't know if I'm going in the right direction at all.

I would to be able to swipe up to drag(?) a new layout into the visible area. This should follow the user's finger movements up and down. This means that the user starts to swipe and the layout is gradually moved into place. When a threshold is reached, the indented element can become final after the finger is released. If the user changes his mind on the fly and move your finger backwards and release it below the threshold, the new layout will not be installed after you release your finger. It would be even cool if the new layout would not only be made visible by its movement, but also its transparency would change from completely transparent to opaque to make it more expressive.

[image: planned layout]

So far I have tried the following code:

fragment_bottom_sheet.xml (the layout that can be dragged into the visible area during the swipe. Now it only has two buttons to make it look like something, and it has a white background colour to make it look like)

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >

    <button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

BottomSheetFragment.kt (The corresponding kotlin class)

```kotlin
class BottomSheetFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }
}
```

I created a custom FrameLayout that can handle the swipe event as described above. Importantly, it only takes up a small area of the screen - see the green area in the diagram - but it should still work when I swipe my finger off it. So it's just the starting trigger point for the swipe.

SwipeFrameLayout.kt

```kotlin
class SwipeFrameLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var startY = 0f
    private var isSwiping = false

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            val bottomSwipeArea = findViewById<View>(R.id.bottom_swipe_area)
            val rect = rect()
            bottomSwipeArea.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect)

            if (rect.contains(ev.rawX.toInt(), ev.rawY.toInt())) {
                startY = ev.y
                isSwiping = true
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }


    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (isSwiping) {
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                isSwiping = false
            }
            return handleSwipe(event)
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun handleSwipe(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                startY = event.y
                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val deltaY = event.y - startY
                val threshold = (context as MainActivity).screenHeight / 3

                if (deltaY < 0 && abs(deltaY) <= threshold) {

                    val interpolator = abs(deltaY) / threshold
                    val translateY = (context as MainActivity).initialY - deltaY * interpolator
                    (context as MainActivity).container.y = translateY

                    Log.d(
                        this::class.java.toString(),
                        "handleSwipe: move" + translateY + ", " + (context as MainActivity).container.height
                    )
                }

                return true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                val deltaY = event.y - startY
                val threshold = (context as MainActivity).screenHeight / 3

                if (abs(deltaY) >= threshold) {
                    (context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, (context as MainActivity).bottomSheetFragment)
                        .commit()
                    Log.d(this::class.java.toString(), "handleSwipe: replace")
                } else {
                    (context as MainActivity).container.y = (context as MainActivity).initialY
                    Log.d(this::class.java.toString(), "handleSwipe: hide")
                }

                return true
            }
            else -> return false
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt calculates a few values just for now

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var bottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetFragment
    lateinit var bottomSwipeArea: SwipeFrameLayout
    lateinit var container: FrameLayout
    var initialY = 0f
    var screenHeight = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        bottomSheetFragment = BottomSheetFragment()
        bottomSwipeArea = findViewById(R.id.bottom_swipe_area)
        container = findViewById(R.id.container)

        screenHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
        container.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object :
            ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                container.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                initialY = container.y
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Finally, the main layout in the activity_main.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".app.main.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/card_margin">

                <TextView
                    style="@style/h1_headline"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:text="@string/app_name" />

<!-- some irrelevant TextView and Button -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <my.example.app.main.SwipeFrameLayout
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_swipe_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:context=".app.main.MainActivity" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorSurfaceVariant"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

According to the logs, the swap happens, but it doesn't show up on the display, and the movement doesn't seem to happen properly, as I would it to (proportionally follow the length of the swipe up to the threshold)

Comment: Have you tried using the existing bottomsheet classes?  https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/package-summary

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, you save my day. I'm just learning android development, and I didn't know how to search for this, for example. Thanks again very much for the tip!